# Good way to start making own Android based Media Center

Tags: java, android, linux, media, center

i heard the rumors about google tv and stuff, but after falling in love
with android and the sdk i tought "why not to have android on my tv".
Some days ago I was looking for hardware for my mini-pc media center computer.

I think it is possible and i think is a good idea too - using android on
custom media center computer, but the question is - how? What type
of hardware i need to make it real. Connecting Htc desire HD to TV
is not the solution :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first bet it to see if there is enough driver support on http://www.android-x86.org/ to do what you need with the hardware you have. If you get the basics, video, sound, network and some form of remote control through an IR driver you'll have to figure out what features you'll want in your Media Center application.

Off the top of my head, this is what I would do:

1. Get Android running on my box, ensuring it can connect to my network, display to my TV and play sounds.
2. Determine all the codecs I want to play, and play each of the movies on the machine to verify.
3. Work on UPnP support to stream movies/photos/music from home computer.
4. Wait patiently until Flash support works on Android-x86 to play hulu

I think you get the idea. This isn't a trivial task but would be really interesting to see if you can come up with something to rivals Boxee.